# How to remove special characters from the string in sybase using patindex

Tags: sql, ascii, special-characters, sybase, patindex

i am having data wich consists of special characters but my output should not display that special characters or ascii characters . I need only alphanumerics and spaces allother character should be replaced with null . Please suggest some way to handle this i came to know patindex will work fine but i am not sure whether it will replaces multiple characters from a string

```
declare @a char
select @a = 'tHo mas@fi5.com'

my output should be tHo masfi5com
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(400)
    Declare @expres as varchar(50) = '%[~,@,#,$,%,&,*,(,),.,!]%'
SET @str = 'tHo mas@fi5.com'
WHILE PATINDEX( @expres, @str ) > 0 
          SET @str = Replace(REPLACE( @str, SUBSTRING( @str, PATINDEX( @expres, @str ), 1 ),''),'-',' ')
print @str
```

Comment: Thanks its working fine but i want to do this check for the entire table for nearly 30 columns . if i use this while condition for each column i need to give 30 updates .  is there any option to do for entire table at asingle shot

Comment: Hi Ramesh,
you can use it like a user function and apply on particular column.